# SuperSleight is scaling my background image

Tags: internet-explorer-6, height, transparency, image-scaling

OK I'm using SuperSleight to fix the background transparencies on the png images in ie6. It all works as it should except it is scaling my background image to 100% height.
I have the following set to 100% because I want my footer to stay at the bottom. It seems like this is affecting SuperSleight and is causing my background image to scale. For most people simply changing the background image format would work but Ive worked a fair amount trying to remove gradient rings and using a png came out with the best result. Does anyone know a fix for this?

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
body{
    background-image:url(../images/content_bg6.png);
    background-color:#3e2f24;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the problem by creating a div wrapper for all the content within the body tag initialized supersleight to that specific wrapper and its children avoiding the body tag.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#pageWrapper').supersleight();
});
```

The above is a work around.